# Using NotesDocument.ConvertToMIME via COM

Tags: excel, vba, com, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I am trying to port some functions from LotusScript to Excel VBA and I am not able to use the method `NotesDocument.ConvertToMIME`.

I can use many other methods and properties of any `NotesDocument` variable, but when I try to use `NotesDocument.ConvertToMIME` I get "Object doesn't support this property or method".

I tried both with early and late binding (declaring `Doc` as `NotesDocument` and `Object`), but the problem is still there.

EDIT

I have release 9.1 and the same method works when used in LotusScript.

EDIT 2

The problem is that Excel VBA doesn't recognize that method:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Quoting from the docs: "This method is new in Release 8.5.1"

Comment: I have release 9.1

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Comment: You could usually count on the Notes/Domino class documentation to note when methods and properties were not available in COM. You stopped being able to count on that several releases ago. And in more than a few cases, I believe newer methods and properties were never supported in COM simply due to cutbacks resulting in inadequate alloation of QA resources to test them. As it is, COM was never even formally supported on Win64, which the majority of use cases will require nowadays, and there definitely are things that didn't work properly on it.